# SQL Select Query for Date Conversion

Tags: sql, date, data-conversion, julian-date

Have been researching all day and so far not found an acceptable answer and my experimenting with code has yielded nothing.

I've got a database with a particular 2 columns "StartDate" and "LastBackupDate" which seem to be storing their date information as a Julian date (eg. 40953.6017873071).  I need to convert this to a standard Gregorian Date (MM-DD-YYYY or DD-MM-YYYY).

I'm pulling back all results from this table at current "Select * FROM xxxxxx WHERE blah blah".

I'm able to convert these dates in no time with Excel, if I export the data to a sheet, but when I pull the data with Convert, I'm unable to get the date converted.

This is part of a SQL query for a webpage.  I can't post out the webcode, but I can post the SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM ExpandedCustomerView WHERE regloginid = @0 AND (Status='A' OR Status='H')"
```

I've been experimenting with this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(36),[STARTDATE],101)
[StartDate]
,[LastBackupDate]
FROM [CNTD_Accounts].[dbo].[ExpandedCustomerView]
```

As a way to get this returned appropriately.  I've tried formatting of 101, 110 and others to see if we can get the right results.  So far, nothing is working for me.  I think this has to be fairly simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cast from number to datetime directly..

```
select cast(40953.6017873071 as datetime)
-- 
2012-02-16 14:26:34.423
```

e.g.

```
cast([StartDate] as datetime)
```

If the data is a number in a varchar field, cast it twice

```
cast(cast([StartDate] as float) as datetime)
```

Comment: Well this was extremely helpful thank you. The cast is definitely changing the displayed date and time. However, I have a new problem that i've broken the web-page attached to it. The Web Grids have a problem with the column name not being defined with the "cast" syntax from SQL. I'm guessing I'll have to figure out a way to define the startdate column differently.   However this definitely worked as requested.  Thank you so much!!!!